# How to add multiple values in an array

Tags: javascript

How to add an array dynamically as in the code below. I have created a multi-dimensional array in JavaScript but how do I push `src` that is `"/_layouts/15/SSNIT.Portal/Images/ssnit02.jpg"` and `title` that is `"MyTitle"`. I have multiple values and I am iterating through them?

```
carousel_images_info = [
    { src: "/_layouts/15/My.Portal/Images/my1.jpg", title: "ssnit01" },
    { src: "/_layouts/15/my3.Portal/Images/my2.jpg", title: "ssnit02" },
    { src: "/_layouts/15/my4.Portal/Images/my3.jpg", title: "ssnit03" },
    { src: "/_layouts/15/my5.Portal/Images/my4.jpg", title: "ssnit04" },
    { src: "/_layouts/15/my5.Portal/Images/ssnit05.jpg", title: "ssnit05" }
];
```

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. You are confusing JavaScript object literals (a construct of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Array.prototype.concat create one array from two simply adding each entry from right to left.

Comment: @Eraden can you show me an example? supposing I have these values above?

Comment: I recommend to [read](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) [resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) to learn the basics about arrays and objects.

Comment: `var a = [1,2,3,4]; var b = [1,2,3]; var c = a.concat(b);` `c` is now `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3]`; Of course members of array may be everything. But if you want add only one member use `push` like bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is array containing objects, you need to push object to it, like:

```
var new_obj = {
    src: "/_layouts/15/SSNIT.Portal/Images/ssnit02.jpg",
    title: "My Title"
};
carousel_images_info.push(new_obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just push :)

```
carousel_images_info.push({ 
    title: "MyTitle",
    src: "/_layouts/15/SSNIT.Portal/Images/ssnit02.jpg"
});
```

However, if you want to avoid duplicates, you'll have to iterate through the entire list to perform a comparison before adding the new row. Another solution could be to push everything then to remove duplicates only when required.

Answer (score 0):

the value for the src and title is dynamic, so can i do like this?

```
  var item_enumerator = this.items.getEnumerator();
  while (item_enumerator.moveNext()) {
    var item = item_enumerator.get_current();
    var image_url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + item.get_item('FileRef');
    var image_title = item.get_item('FileLeafRef'); 
    var set = {
      src: image_url,
      title : image_title
    };
    this.carousel_images_info.push(set);
  }
```

Comment: If the above is correct then it should be fine, but my carousel images does not work, probably because this.carousel_images_info is being accessed first by another function before it is populated.

Comment: `getEnumerator` - what's that? Seems the code is quite unrelated to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
var new_obj = {};
new_obj.src = "/_layouts/15/SSNIT.Portal/Images/ssnit02.jpg";
new_obj.title= "MyTitle";

carousel_images_info[carousel_images_info.length] = new_obj
```

So make a function if you are doing this dynamically,

```
carousel_images_info=[];

function Insert(xSrc,xTitle)
{
    var new_obj = {};
    new_obj.src = xSrc;
    new_obj.title= xTitle;

    carousel_images_info[carousel_images_info.length] = new_obj;
}

Insert("/_layouts/15/SSNIT.Portal/Images/ssnit02.jpg","MyTitle");
```